# Bag of Words formation for articles

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to play around with the 20 NewsGroups dataset in `sklearn`. I have used the following code to import all the training and testing data into 2 `utils.Bunch` structures:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

# Import Newsgroup data
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')
newsgroups_test= fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test')
```

My end goal is to use a naive bayes classifier on the dataset to learn how it works and see how accurate I can make it. I'm trying to prep the dataset for the classifier by representing it with the 'bag-of-words' representation.

By my research, I should be able to accomplish this with the [`sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html)

However, I'm unclear as to how to implement this seeing as the two data structures I have are unusual and I'm not sure how to pull the data out of them.

Comment: do you want to know how to prepare model for bag of words or is it something else you are curious about here?

Comment: I want to know how I can use the HashingVectorizer to prepare model for bag of words

Comment: Hashing vector has no inverse function, it's usually more appropriate to use [`CountVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html).

Comment: @ncfirth How would I use that?

Comment: Similarly to the bellow answer. I think you need to do a bit of reading on the approaches you want to use before asking more questions on SO, maybe start [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-bag-words-model/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After loading the data using your code, `newsgroups_train` is a dictionary with the following keys:

```
In [3]: newsgroups_train.keys()
Out[3]: dict_keys(['data', 'filenames', 'target_names', 'target', 'DESCR', 'description'])
```

You can simply get the data via:

```
train_data = newsgroups_train["data"]
test_data = newsgroups_test["data"]
```

And it is stored as a list of strings. Then, you can simply apply the HashVectorizer function on `data`.

You should be getting sparse matrix for your train and test data via `.fit()` and then `.transform()`. For example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
h = HashingVectorizer()
h.fit(train_data)
h_train = h.transform(train_data)
h_test = h.transform(test_data)
```

Then, `h_train` and `h_test` will be sparse matrices.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you elaborate on the `fit()` and `transform` a bit more? Are they both operations that I need to do in sequence?

Comment: I see. I can get that if I run what you've mentioned. If I could question you a little further, I've uploaded an image of the sparse matrix for `h_test` below in this comment. Can you tell me what it is and how exactly I should read this? It's really interesting but I feel a little out of my depth:  https://imgur.com/a/rfZMK

Comment: @tushariyer I didn't find `h_test`

Comment: sorry, its for `h_train`. I'm using the variable explorer in Anaconda-spyder